# mysql case statement for counting

Tags: mysql, case

**Table t1**

```
col1 col2 col3
---- ---- ----
  1   cat   2
  2   dog   3
  3   cat   4
  4   dog   5
```

**Table t2**

```
 id  type
---- ----
  1    a
  2    a
  3    b
  4    b
```

I want to transform it such that it becomes this:

```
col2   a    b
---- ---- ----
 cat   2    4
 dog   3    5
```

**Query**

```
Select t1.col2, 
case when t2.type = 'a' then count(t1.col3) end as a,
case when t2.ab = 'b' then count(t1.col3) end as b 
From mytable t1 join mytable2 t2 on t1.col1=t2.id where t1.col3 is not null 
group by 1;
```

**It populates only a or b column**.

What is wrong with my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the case statement into the count() (or sum()) itself:

```
Select t1.col2, 
       count(case when t2.type = 'a' then 1 else null end) as a,
       count(case when t2.type = 'b' then 1 else null end) as b 
From mytable t1 join mytable2 t2 on t1.col1=t2.id where t1.col3 is not null 
group by 1;
```